# Nginx - Wrong PHP_Values

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I run NewRelic to track my applications, I set the Application name in my server blocks in nginx like `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=Store";` it seems to get cached how how as when I go to another domain I have the same result even though the appname has been set as something different..

This has only started happening recently (I believe it was after a upgrade - My bad..)

I restarted the server and went on the other domain first and it set the correct appname but then when I go to another domain that same appname is set so I think its caching it or using the same php process.

Can anyone help, please ask if you require extra info.

Comment: Are you using completely separate fastcgi application pools for each site?

Comment: @DerfK I dont think so.